# 2 levels of joins LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have 3 objects that I need to link together

Parent: TblClients

This will have multiple children of Type TblBusinessLeads , the key between the two is ClientID

Type Lead will have multiple children of type TblFeeBreakouts , the key between the two is LeadID

I have written the following LINQ to get the databack, but it is not coming back (out of memory exception)

```
from t0 in TblClients
join t1 in TblBusinessLeads on t0.ClientID equals t1.ClientID into t1_join
from t1 in t1_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t3 in TblFeeBreakouts on t1.LeadID equals t3.LeadID into t3_join
from t3 in t3_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby
t0.ClientID,
t1.LeadID
select new {
            client_data = t0,
            business_lead_data = t1_join,
            fee_breakout_data = t3_join
}
```

I am not sure of you can even do this, but the idea seems pretty common. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**:
Wow lot of comments. Here goes my answers
I am trying to run the query in LinqPad, thats where the Out of Memory is Occuring
If I look at the SQL generated, it gives me

```
SELECT [t0].[ClientID], [t0].[ClientName], [t0].[ClientDesc], [t0].[EditedBy], [t0].[EditedDate], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[CreatedDate], [t3].[LeadID], [t3].[InitiativeName], [t3].[Description], [t3].[NewBusNeeds], [t3].[CreativeNeeds], [t3].[IdeationNeeds], [t3].[Comments], [t3].[LossReasons], [t3].[OriginDate], [t3].[DateReceivedAssignment], [t3].[DueDate], [t3].[TimelineNotes], [t3].[PendingCode], [t3].[EstStartDate], [t3].[EstEndDate], [t3].[ExeStartDate], [t3].[ExeEndDate], [t3].[Probable80Total], [t3].[Possible50Total], [t3].[Emerging25Total], [t3].[NoBudget0Total], [t3].[TotalBudget], [t3].[FinancialNotes], [t3].[DollarsRecordFor], [t3].[BizDevContactUserID], [t3].[BizDevContact2UserID], [t3].[SVPContactUserID], [t3].[ClientMgmtContactUserID], [t3].[CMAdditionalContactUserID], [t3].[AdditionalContactUserID], [t3].[CreatorUserID], [t3].[OfficeID], [t3].[ClientID] AS [ClientID2], [t3].[LeadTypeID], [t3].[ActionNeeded], [t3].[ActionDate], [t3].[NewBusDeliveryDate], [t3].[NewBusDesc], [t3].[CreativeDeliveryDate], [t3].[CreativeDesc], [t3].[IdeationDeliveryDate], [t3].[IdeationDesc], [t3].[AltMediaDeliveryDate], [t3].[AltMediaDesc], [t3].[MobileOpsDeliveryDate], [t3].[MobileOpsDesc], [t3].[EventsDeliveryDate], [t3].[EventsDesc], [t3].[Routing], [t3].[RoutingDate], [t3].[Deleted], [t3].[LeadSourceID], [t3].[NatureofLeadID], [t3].[NatureofLeadNotes], [t3].[EditedBy] AS [EditedBy2], [t3].[EditedDate] AS [EditedDate2], [t3].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy2], [t3].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate2], [t3].[ClientContactName], [t3].[ClientContactTitle], [t3].[ReportingYear], (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [tblBusinessLead] AS [t4]
WHERE [t0].[ClientID] = [t4].[ClientID]
) AS [value], [t1].[LeadID] AS [LeadID2]
 FROM [tblClient] AS [t0]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblBusinessLead] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ClientID] = [t1].[ClientID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblFeeBreakout] AS [t2] ON [t1].[LeadID] = [t2].[LeadID]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblBusinessLead] AS [t3] ON [t0].[ClientID] = [t3].[ClientID]
 ORDER BY [t0].[ClientID], [t1].[LeadID], [t2].[LeadID], [t2].[FeeTypeID], [t3].    [LeadID]
```

This returns like 1.2 million rows

There is no mapping in the model becuase the DB has no relationships (they are inferred, no foreign keys or anything like that)

The reason I am using t1_join and t3_join is because if I use t1 or t3, I get the single entity, not the IEnumerable of the object, hence I cant loop over it.

If you have more questions, please ask.

Comment: @JeffMercado - they are needed if he is trying to do a LEFT JOIN...

Comment: @IsaacLevin - is this LinQ-to-Entities? What is the size of the result set if you run this in SQL? Can you also include the entire statement in your code snippet (the assignment statement and any casting if there is)

Comment: Do you have a many-to-many mapping between your entities? You could then avoid the joins and just reference the navigation properties.

Comment: Out of memory exception from within the LINQ query directly?  Is the error coming from SQL or .NET?

Comment: Didn't you mean to write select new {
            client_data = t0,
            business_lead_data = t1,
            fee_breakout_data = t3
}

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: Oh oops, I thought the calls were on the tables themselves, not the groupings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what possible use could a client have for 1.2 million rows? There is no real good use case for this, so your first step should be figuring out how to filter your results appropriately.

Second, I believe the reason your query is returning `OutOfMemoryException` is because LinQPad is doing a `ToList()` or something similar so that I can show the results of the query in the bottom pane. The `ToList()` is loading all 1.2 million rows into memory. If you ran the query in a regular .Net app, the following will return an `IQueryable<>` which will not load into memory.

```
var query = 
from t0 in TblClients
join t1 in TblBusinessLeads on t0.ClientID equals t1.ClientID into t1_join
from t1 in t1_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t3 in TblFeeBreakouts on t1.LeadID equals t3.LeadID into t3_join
from t3 in t3_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby
t0.ClientID,
t1.LeadID
select new {
            client_data = t0,
            business_lead_data = t1_join,
            fee_breakout_data = t3_join
};
```

Comment: You are right about the filtering, but copy/paste the OP's code into an IQueryable variable is not really meaningful. One day it should be enumerated anyway.

Comment: I believe more than a few of these methods - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable_methods.aspx - do not require the entire result to be enumerated...Is that not meaningful?

Comment: Sure, but the OP can do that anyway, with or without variable. Filtering is the point.

Comment: The variable enables the client to have an object of `IQueryable<>` implementation, which can be used for multiple and as many filtering options as are possible with the interface. I am showing him how he can maintain his query and achieve filtering however he likes (to avoid 1.2 mil records). This is certainly meaningful and is not an uncommon technique.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, it is probably a good idea to setup asociations on these tables, which I did... The LINQ for the result after the association was simple

var clientList = (from a in tblClients
                              select a).ToList();

From there it was just accessing the properties.